# como saber se uma classe é imutável pelo JavaDOC?

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber se como, pelo JavaDOC saber se uma classe é imutável ou não. Existe algum campo no JavDOC para consulta rápida, pois estou usando varias classes e não tenho muito contato com a linguagem. gostaria da resposta e, se possível, uma imagem. Obrigado.
    Estou trabalhando com shapes. Seria bom se essa classe fosse usada como exemplo.

Comment: Imagem de que você espera na resposta? Não entendi.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5124214/5524514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve olhar se o construtor é privado, geralmente recomenda-se usar ele privado e criar um método público of() que devolve um novo objeto.
Se ela tem setteres, se ela não tiver você não terá como alterar os valores.

Comment: Uma classe pode ser imutável e ter construtor público. Veja por exemplo `String`.

Comment: Pode mesmo! Vou ajustar a resposta.